# why there is no file spring-rabbit.xsd under http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/

Tags: spring, spring-rabbit

**Why http://www.springframework.org keep united way on providing spring-[schema].xsd file.**

Today, I coincidentally find that there is no file named spring-rabbit.xsd under URI http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/. But, mostly other schemas have the xsd file named using spring- suffix with their name, i.e : spring-beans.xsd is under http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/.

So, i'm confused and curious about why this happens?

Here the pictures showing this situation.
[image: spring rabbit without spring-rabbit.xsd file in it]

[image: spring beans whit spring-beans.xsd file in it]

---

I'm using eclipse to develop my spring project, and the head definition in one of my xml config files is showing bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">            
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
```

With using `http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd`, i get eclipse XML problem: 
`cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'rabbit:admin'.   application-consumer.xml    /my-spring-project/src/main/resources/config    line 16 XML Problem`

If i using `http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd`, there is no XML problem.

So, that's why i'm confused, should `http://www.springframework.org` provide `http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd` like they do in other schema such as beans , data , context and so on.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-data.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary - spring maps to the appropriate schema for the version you are using, from the jar (the mapping is in `/META-INF/spring.schemas`).

The schemas on the internet are not used at all.

**EDIT**

The link is there now.

Comment: I add additional infomation to my question, problem exists in eclipse, and no errors in execute environment. Why `http://www.springframework.org` keep united way on providing spring-[schema].xsd file.

Comment: I will add the link, but it's generally better to use a Spring-aware IDE (such as the spring eclipse plugins, or the [STS eclipse bundle](https://spring.io/tools/sts), and enable Spring Nature on the project), or IntelliJ IDEA; these IDEs know how Spring resolves the schema.

Comment: The link is there now.